# Exclude in elasticsearch query gives failed to parse search source. expected field name but got [START_OBJECT]

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, kibana

I have following query, which 
1. get all data with logtype error.
2. exclude all data in which there is `error occured` in logmessage fields.

```
curl -s -XGET 'localhost:9200/index_name/type/_search?pretty=true&size=10' -d '
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "logtype" : "error"
        },
        "should": {
            "bool": {
               "must_not": {
                  "match": {
                     "logMessage": "*error occured*"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
    }
}
'
```

But the above command gives:

```
 {
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [{
            "type": "parse_exception",
            "reason": "failed to parse search source. expected field name but got [START_OBJECT]"
        }],
        "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
        "reason": "all shards failed",
        "phase": "query",
        "grouped": true,
        "failed_shards": [{
            "shard": 0,
            "index": "indexname",
            "node": "HxII3rajS4KP5dkP-ZvPSw",
            "reason": {
                "type": "parse_exception",
                "reason": "failed to parse search source. expected field name but got [START_OBJECT]"
            }
        }]
    },
    "status": 400
 }
```

How can it be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
curl -s -XGET 'localhost:9200/index_name/type/_search?pretty=true&size=10' -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "logtype": "error"
        }
      },
      "must_not": {
         "match": {
           "logMessage": "*error occured*"
         }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Any tutorial for the same?

Comment: While the above query is working, it's not working in case of regex. I need to pass whole string in `logMessage` to remove it from search result.

Comment: Feel free to create another question with your specific problem.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with my regex. I need to rewrite it. I want to match anything before and after error occured.

Comment: I asked another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42524616/elasticsearch-must-not-query-doesnt-match-regex