# Elasticsearch must_not query doesn't match regex

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, kibana

I want to filter out all documents where `Too many connections` are present in LogMessage field.

The query I wrote is:

```
'
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "logType": "Error"
        }
      },
      "must_not": {
         "match": {
           "LogMessage": ".*Too many connections.*"
         }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

On the other hand, if I am using my whole string in `LogMessage` field, it's working fine.

I have verified my regex here:

```
https://regex101.com/r/EexTmV/1
```

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use a [`regexp` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) instead of a `match` query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "logType": "Error"
        }
      },
      "must_not": {
         "regexp": {
           "LogMessage": ".*Too many connections.*"
         }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yup, I had this confusion I thought match could use regex... but it doesn't I think I read somewhere on StackOverflow Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709100/how-do-i-do-a-partial-match-in-elasticsearch where he recommended to use regex in match that did not work for me...